# Green function must be spatial symmetric, where am I wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, greens-function

My problem is to find the Green function $g(r;\tilde{r})$ of:
$$ sg - \frac{1}{{{r^2}}}\frac{d}{{dr}}\left( {{r ^2}\frac{{dg}}{{dr}}} \right) = \delta (r - \tilde r){e^{ - s\tilde t }}$$
with
$$ g( \pm 1;\tilde{r})=0$$

Below is my solution:

Note that $g'(r)$ is not continuous at $r=\tilde{r}$, so we need to solve the equation in two different domains: $[-1,\tilde{r})$ with $g(-1;\tilde{r})=0$, and $(\tilde{r},1]$ with $g(1;\tilde{r})=0$. Thus we have
$$g(r;\tilde{r})=C_1\frac{\sinh\sqrt{s}(1+r)}{r}, r\in [-1,\tilde{r})$$
$$g(r;\tilde{r})=C_2\frac{\sinh\sqrt{s}(1-r)}{r}, r\in (\tilde{r},1]$$
Due to the continuity of $g(r;\tilde{r})$ at $r=\tilde{r}$, we have **eq.1**:
$${C_1}\sinh \sqrt s (1 + \tilde r ) = {C_2}\sinh \sqrt s (1 - \tilde r )$$
Integrate the original differential equation by weight of $r^2$ from $(\tilde r-\epsilon,\tilde r+\epsilon)$ with respect to $r$, and then take $\epsilon\rightarrow0$, we obtain
$$\left( {\frac{{dg}}{{dr}}} \right)_{{{\tilde r}^ - }}^{{{\tilde r }^ + }} =  - {e^{ - s\tilde t }}$$
So we have **eq.2**:
$${C_1}\cosh \sqrt s (1 + \tilde r ) + {C_2}\cosh \sqrt s (1 - \tilde r ) = \frac{{\tilde r {e^{ - s\tilde t }}}}{{\sqrt s }}$$
By **eq.1** and **eq.2** we get
$${C_1} = \frac{{\tilde r \sinh \sqrt s (1 - \tilde r)}}{{\sqrt s \sinh 2\sqrt s }}{e^{ - s\tilde t }}$$
$${C_2} = \frac{{\tilde r \sinh \sqrt s (1 + \tilde r )}}{{\sqrt s \sinh 2\sqrt s }}{e^{ - s\tilde t }}$$
Finally, we obtain the solution to the problem:
$$g(r;\tilde r) = \frac{{\tilde r}}{r}\frac{{\sinh \sqrt s (1 + r)\sinh \sqrt s (1 - \tilde r)}}{{\sqrt s \sinh 2\sqrt s }}{e^{ - s\tilde \tau }}, r<\tilde r$$
$$g(r;\tilde r) = \frac{{\tilde r}}{r}\frac{{\sinh \sqrt s (1 - r)\sinh \sqrt s (1 + \tilde r)}}{{\sqrt s \sinh 2\sqrt s }}{e^{ - s\tilde \tau }},r>\tilde r$$
Rewritten as
$$g(r;\tilde r) = \frac{{\tilde r}}{r}\frac{{\cosh \sqrt s (2 - \left| {r - \tilde r} \right|) - \cosh\sqrt s (r + \tilde r)}}{{2\sqrt s \sinh 2\sqrt s }}{e^{ - s\tilde \tau }}$$
My question is, the Green function must be spatial symmetric, that means $g(r;\tilde r)=g(\tilde r;r)$, but my solution doesn't match that feature, so where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why must the green function be symmetric?

Comment: It has to do with solving the partial differential equation $\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial t}} - \frac{1}{{{r^2}}}\frac{\partial }{{\partial r}}\left( {{r^2}\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial r}}} \right) = f(r,t)$ by the Green function method. If it is not symmetric, the solution expressed by the Green function may not be correct.

Comment: Now I know that the equation can be simplified to make it easier to be dealt with by the Green function method: $\left( {\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}} - \frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {r^2}}}} \right)(rT) = rf(r,t)$ . But I didn't notice that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally know where I was wrong. The Green function for the differential equation is spatial symmetric only with weight of $r^2$, that is $r^2g(r;\tilde r)=\tilde r^2g(\tilde r,r)$.